# Как сделать переадресацию на предыдущую страницу?

Tags: python, django

У меня есть страница с удалением постов на сайте. На странице с удалением есть кнопка назад и я хочу что бы эта кнопка "назад" переадресовывола пользователя на предыдущую страницу,но не знаю как это сделать!Пробовал сделать метод в моделях,в шаблоне у кнопки в href="{{post.get_succes_url}}",но ничего не получилось,в просмотре кода страницы не было ссылки

МЕТОД В МОДЕЛЯХ:

```
def get_succes_url(self,request):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796195/how-to-redirect-to-previous-page-in-django-after-post-request/35796559

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обязательно ли это делать в django?
Можно обойтись более простым кодом:

```
<input type="button" onclick="history.back();" value="Пред. страница"/>
```

Comment: Спасибо,помогло!